# Dates not appearing consistently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

The following code runs for a jQuery UI datepicker. Dates are highlighted based on whether a JSON response contains data for that date. This works fine in Chrome (32.0.1675.2 canary) but not in Firefox. Anyone know why that might be? The highlight class is not added in FF.

```
function( response ) {
            MyApp.events = response;
            //console.log(events[1]);
            $("#my-event-calendar" ).datepicker({

                beforeShowDay: function(date) {

                    var result = [true, '', null];
                    var matching = $.grep(MyApp.events, function(event) {
                        //console.log(new Date(event.Date).valueOf() );
                        dateToHighlight = new Date(event.Date).valueOf();
                        return dateToHighlight === date.valueOf();
                    });

                    if (matching.length) {
                        result = [true, 'highlight', null];
                    }

                    return result;
                },
```

In Chrome, `console.log(new Date(event.Date).valueOf() );` renders `1380582000000` but in Firefox this is `-1775005200000`

**Update**, The JSON data is now formatted as follows:

Object {Date: "2013-10-02T14:30:00+00:00", Title: "Title of event"}

Comment: It seems that one browser is treating *10/01/13* as 1913 and the other as 2013. Is that supposed to be 10 January or 1 October? A format like 2013-10-01 is far less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

As Quantas person says, letting the Date function parse strings is not a good idea. Far better to manually parse date strings. Also, don't use 2 digit years.

In this case it seems you need a function like:

```
// Expects date in format m/d/yy
// where all years are +2000
function parseEventDate(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(+s[2]+2000, ++s[0], s[1]);
}
```

to convert the date string to a date object. Note that the date object will be created based on the client's system settings.

#### Edit

You're now using an ISO8601 format like 2013-10-02T14:30:00+00:00. While this is consistent with ES5, it is not supported by the Date.parse method of maybe 25% of browsers in use (depending on whose statistics you believe), so the best way is still to manually parse the string.

The following assumes the date and time are UTC (which is what ES5 requires):

```
// Expects date in format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ
// Assumes timezone offset is 0000
function parseEventDate(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]));
}
```

If you want to include the timezone offset, a little more work is required but not much.

Comment: Another issue with both of ours - it's ambiguous regarding date format (MM/DD/YY or DD/MM/YY).

Comment: Yes, however that's what the OP had.